# Split video on resolution change

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution

I have a video that switches between 3008x3008 and 480x480 resolutions.
I would like to extract each 3008x3008 section of the video into their own videos.
I've been able to achieve this with Python and OpenCV, this is slow and doesn't maintain variable framerates.

```py
import cv2 as cv

def process_day(video_file: str):
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_file)
    frame_count = 0
    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
    fps = 8  # Variable frame rates will not be maintained.
    video_writer = None
    while cap.isOpened():
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame_count += 1
        if frame.shape[:2] == (3008, 3008):
            if video_writer is None:
                video_writer = cv.VideoWriter(f"{frame_count}.avi", fourcc, fps, frame.shape[:2])
            video_writer.write(frame)
        else:
            video_writer = None
        if frame_count % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"{frame_count/cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)}% Processed.")
```

I'm hoping for a faster solution, or some FFmpeg magic.
Maintaining variable framerates or being able to timestamp output videos would be a bonus.

Edit: For context, there are many videos I want to perform this on. Most videos are 24 hours long camera recordings that switch to high resolution during periods of motion.

Comment: What container and codec?

Comment: @Gyan Your choice of AVI/MP4. Codec is H264.

Comment: That is for the input?

Comment: Yep. Output ideally in the same format.